# how to get text from outside of 'a' tags and listed in between them in python using scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

```
<div class="breadcrumbs pt10 pb10">
<a>Location :</a> 
"National Harbor                    ,
            Maryland" 
<br>
<a href="#" class="type">Venue : </a>
"Gaylord National Resort & Convention Center "
</div>
```

How to get text National Harbor, Maryland, Gaylord National Resort & Convention Center from above in python using scrapy?
i applied this code.."response.selector.xpath('//div[@class="breadcrumbs pt10 pb10"]/a/text()').extract()"....But o/p i'm getting like this.."[u'Location :', u'Venue : ']". Can anyone help please? Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can directly use `response.xpath`

2) `//div[@class='breadcrumbs pt10 pb10']/text()` will help